# How to find disk usage per table of Hsql database (using SQL, DataGrip or other solutions)?

Tags: database, hsqldb, datagrip

I have 2 hsql database which are supposed to hold the same information. However, one is taking 4x time more space on disk (1 GB versus c. 250 MB). The database holds plenty of tables and I would like a way to know disk usage of each table (hence I might find where the pb is coming from).
I am using DataGrip but I could not find a way either with DataGrip or with plain SQL to have such information.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From version 2.5.1, HyperSQL supports a feature called `table spaces`. When this is enabled, each table that holds over a certain amount of disk space is allocated its own space. An INFORMATION_SCHEMA view shows the spaces allocated to different tables.

Details are documented in the Guide: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#tspace_usage